# Как отправить данные на url через requests на python

Tags: python, requests

Допустим мне нужно отправить:
`username=username&version=version`
И эти данные нужно отправить к примеру на какой нибудь сайт.
Возможно ли это с помощью `requests`?
Если нет, то каким способом ещё можно?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: "Возможно ли это с помощью requests?" да можно.

Comment: для этого requests и существует. Пользуйтесь

Answer (score 0):

```
payload = {'username': 'value1', 'version': 'value2'}

r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/get', params=payload)
print(r.url)
```

> https://httpbin.org/get?username=value1&version=value2

Ответы на все вопросы в документации:

https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/

Comment: Так не пойдёт, приведите и код тоже. Для ответа одной ссылки на документацию недостаточно.